# Woocommerce REST API allow normal users make an order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, api

We are making an application that can make an order from the mobile for Woocommerce API, when I used a loggedin user with token for validate the authentication, its showing error:

```
Sorry, you cannot view this resource.
```

But when I am using Administrator, its works. How I can make an other for regular user (non-admin)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins (such as woocommerce) off-topic so you might notice some down-votes and answers may be slow if they come at all. Have you tried asking the plugin author? You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found our my solution by customize "woocommerce_rest_check_permissions"